# iOS app disappears from notification center after denying notification permissions from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have a react native app and we have a dependency on [react-native-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app) in our `package.json` to request push notification permissions and deliver the notifications. When the user first installs or re-installs the app, we display a screen asking users if we can send them push notifications. We use the firebase messaging [requestPermission](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#requestPermission) method to request permission to deliver push notifications, which changes the `firebase.messaging.AuthorizationStatus` from `NOT_DETERMINED` to `AUTHORIZED`. I assume the firebase module calls native ios code like [requestAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications) to authorize notification delivery.

If they choose not to enable notifications, we update our redux state value `hasAskedForPushPermissions` to true and we don't ever ask them again if they want to enable push notifications, unless they delete and re-install the app. However after choosing not to enable push notifications, the app doesn't appear under `settings -> notifications`. If I scroll down `settings` to all the apps on my iphone, my app appears  but there's no option to enable notifications. Now our users have no way of enabling push notifications after denying them the first time, besides deleting the app and re-installing which obviously is a huge pain. Can anyone shed some light into why my app doesn't appear under `settings -> notifications`?

Comment: Do you ask if they want notifications in your own dialog and then present the iOS native dialog based on that? Or do you always trigger the iOS dialog?  It is the act of calling the iOS native dialog that results in the app settings being visible.

Comment: By the way, it is quite safe to ask for notification permissions every time. iOS will make sure the user is only shown the request dialog once

Comment: @Paulw11 you're saying I should always call the iOS native dialog every time the user opens the app?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am doing the former where I ask if they want notifications in my own dialog, then present the iOS native dialog based on that.

Comment: You can present a screen that explains why you want notifications if you want, but then after they dismiss that screen, trigger the iOS request. Let them answer yes/no to iOS. That way the notification settings will be in your app settings and they can change their answer. If you don't want to show the "explainer" screen you can just ask every time. iOS ensures they are only asked once.